# Return string from promise result

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-translate

I want to have an wrapper function arround this `$translate` service: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service so we can use those function easily in our code by calling $language.translate('keyword') instead of the promise.

So, I create a new service in my app which should do that work. It's a very simple function but it's returning `undefined` or `[Object Object]`.

```
 angularApp.factory("$language", ['$translate', function($translate){

    function trans(keyword){
        console.log("translate in $language", keyword);

        return $translate(keyword).then(function(msg) {
            console.log("translation successfull", msg);
            return msg;
        }, function(translationId){
            console.log("translation is not known", translationId);
            return translationId
        })
    }

    return {
        translate : trans
    }
}]);
```

In both cases, when translation is known or not, the `console.log()` shows me the right string, but on my page it's showing [object object] or undefined (when I remove the first `return` right before `$translate(keyword)`. 
When I use the filter like `{{:: "KEYWORD" | translate}}` it works fine.

How can I let my function return the string with the translation or the translationId (which is actually the same as the keyword when there is no translation found)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're expecting result to be in synchronous manner, if you're using async variant, anyways it would be going to return `Promise` object.

It seem like you could use `synchronous` variant of `$translate` service using `$translate.instant()`, but downside of this `sync` variant. You won't receive an error code, if anything happens in between translation process.

**Rewrite**

```
angularApp.factory("$language", ['$translate', '$sce', function($translate, $sce){

    function trans(keyword){
        console.log("translate in $language", keyword);

        var translation = $translate.instant(keyword)
        var msg = $sce.valueOf(translation);
        if (msg) {
            console.log("translation successfull", msg);
            return msg;
        }
        else {
            console.log("translation is not known");
            return "Error"
        }
    }

    return {
        translate : trans
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I needed!

Comment: @NVO Glad to see it helped, Thanks :)